# Someone suggest the optimal spacing between content and the ad

Tags: google-adsense, website-design, website-features, google-adsense-policies

Based on logs, I conclude based on $0 RPM that adsense has an issue with the picture pages on my mobile site, and I think it all comes down to optimal spacing which I think I have not yet nailed. The spacing I'm talking about is highlighted in red braces.

[image: Spacing]

The reason why I display the picture before the content is because that is what most people want from the site. They don't care about reading as much.

I do have the picture generated via an automatically generated IMG tag in javascript which is executed in completion BEFORE the adsense code is initiated, so I feel that shouldn't be a problem, and webpagetest.org confirmed the execution order for me.

Now I think it comes down to ad spacing or some other ridiculous requirement google has.

I did read somewhere that google suggests a minimum spacing of 150 pixels between game controls and ads but I think that is ridiculous for a mobile site, especially when screen sizes can be as small as 320x240px I think. Well at least the screen I'm using is about that small.

I also did configure my viewport correctly, otherwise you would see a sideways scrollbar.

I think my spacing isn't 100% optimal but I'm open to other answers that would help me further.

Comment: Excellently defined scenario. I wish I had an answer! It seem that the whole *what is acceptable* with big G is really a mystery. But perhaps with some experience, someone might have some ideas for you. As for me, I am just as clueless as you are- more likely more clueless!! I just had a flash back to the movie... perhaps not that clueless.